# Need Help with MVC workflow - post to another server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I have a form where I'm collecting contact information (name, address, etc) for an e-commerce app. When the user clicks the Buy button, I want to parse the form, grab a couple of values, and generate a crypto fingerprint.

Then I want to take all of the form values (name, address, etc) from the posted form and redirect that to a new server with the same form values. I may need to inject a few new ones behind the scenes.

No problem capturing the info after the click. I'm just using a Buy action on my controller. The part I can't figure out is posting to the other server with the desired parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Buy(BuyModel model)
{
    var fingerprint = GenerateFingerprint(.....);

    return Redirect("https://some.other.url.com/");
}
```

EDIT: To clarify. I don't need to just post the data, I actually need to display the response in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK guys, here is what I ended up doing, and it works great.

For the purposes of this discussion, there are 2 views. Membership collects info from the user, and Buy executes the post to the 3rd-party server.

When the user clicks the OK button on the Membership view, the first block of code below gets executed - the HttpPost on the Membership action. Here the info is manipulated if necessary and then saved in TempData so that it can be passed to the Buy view. It then redirects control to the Buy view.

In the Buy action, the second block of code below gets executed. Here, I can grab the stuff collected in Membership and do whatever I need to do. Then copy all of the form data into ViewData[] values. You could use the model instead of ViewData, but I have other stuff in the model. Probably could have combined them, but this works.

Finally, in the Buy view, set all of the form field values using the ViewData values. The key, though is using the jQuery .ready handler so that the form gets submitted automatically when the page is done loading.

So this basically copies the form values from Membership view into the Buy view, adds a few new values and then posts it all to a 3rd-party URL.

**BuyController.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Membership(OtherModel model)
    {
        // do some stuff with the model
        // ...

        TempData["OtherModel"] = model;       

        return RedirectToAction("Buy");
    }
```

...

```
    public ActionResult Buy()
    {
        // do some stuff to generate crypto key
        var fingerprint = DoSomeStuff();

        ViewData["x_fp_hash"] = fingerprint;

        var otherstuff = (OtherModel) TempData["OtherModel"];
        ViewData["x_login"] = otherstuff.login;


        return View(model);
    }
```

**Buy.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBlank.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Validating ...";
}

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $("form#simForm").submit();
    });
</script>


@model My.Namespace.MyModel


    <form id="simForm" runat="server" method='post' action='https://xxxxxx.net/url/transact.dll'>
        <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_login' id='x_login' value="@ViewData["x_login"]" />
        <input type='hidden' runat="server" name='x_fp_hash' id='x_fp_hash'value="@ViewData["x_fp_hash"]"/>

        etc.

    </form>
```

Comment: I appreciate you posting the answer you came up with, but what you did was essentially what I told you to do, although you fleshed it out more.  I don't mind that you gave yourself the answer, since yours is more complete, but you could at least upvote people that help you.  That's what the community is all about.  Otherwise, you're asking people for help, taking their advice, and then not giving them any credit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class to make the post to the other server and then redirect as normal.

```
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/mypage/;
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

For the post data, you'll want to convert this to a `byte[]` and then add it to a `stream`.

```
string postData = "key=value&key2=value2";
byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

You'll then be able to set the ContentLength of the request correctly:

```
httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;
```

Write this to a `Stream` and we're good to do the post:

```
 using(Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
}
```

Assuming you don't need the user to be redirected to the posted page, this will work well. You can look in the `webResponse` object to find out what happened with the post if that's useful to you.

Comment: That doesn't actually work the way he expects it would.  Most people expect to be able to return the contents of the post to the user, and simply redirecting will cause a get after the post.

Comment: All posts should be turned into GETs anyway. The PRG pattern is pretty important.

Comment: PRG is important when you are posting to your own site.  Posting to a different site means you can't control how the other site works.  If the other site uses the PRG method, then you can just take the results of the post and redirect the user using the 301/2 url.  If not, what you suggest won't work.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Let's hope he either has control over the other site he's posting too, or doesn't really need the redirect but just the response in order to continue.

Comment: OK ... so this didn't work. I actually need the browser to redirect. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can post the values to another url and redirect in the same post (that is, return the user to the resulting page of the post) is to actually make the users browser do the post.  You're also doing the post to an HTTPS, so the whole point is to prevent man-in-the-middle kinds of things.

The only real way to do this is to return a new form to the user, and programmatically tell the browser to submit it using javascript with the new values.